# Making shallow copy inside assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I need to implement an assignment operator for a class with a lot of members which I don't want to assign manually. Can I first make a shallow memory copy and then perform the necessary initializations?

```
class C
{
    public:
    C &operator=(const C &rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs == this)
            return *this;
        memcpy(this, &rhs, sizeof(C));
        Init(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    .........
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you must check for self assignment first. e.g. if(this == &rhs) return *this;

Comment: @mcnicholls: Well, the ideal way to implement `=` is by **Copy and Swap Idiom**.

Comment: @Als: yes I do recall seeing this method and it does look like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Unless the object has a POD type, this is undefined behavior.  And
a user defined assignment operator means that it's not a POD.  And in
practice, it could fail for a number of reasons.

One possible solution is to define a nested POD type with the data 
members, and simply assign it, e.g.:

```
class C
{
    struct Data { /* ... */ };
    Data myData;
public:
    C& operator=( C const& other )
    {
        myData = other.myData;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Of course, that means that you need to constantly refer to each member
as `myData.x`, rather than simply `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could, but all your copied pointer members(if any) will then point to the same object and if that object goes out of scope, You would be left with a dangling pointer for all other objects which refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to dereference a C++ reference using the * operator. Unless you have operator* defined for this class it's not gonna work.

I mean in line

```
memcpy(this, *rhs, sizeof(C));
```